# Using Visual Studio Code for vb.net : How to enable vb.net intellisense?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-code

I program in vb.net, I'm switching from visual studio big edition to vs code to be more portable.

One feature I really miss is intellisense ? Can I make it work with vb.net ?

While searching I ended up on this page

```
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense
```

They say 8 languages are supported out of the box, but doesn't include vb.net or C# and that you should check on the marketplace for more

I checked on the marketplace and I can't seem to find it ?

Is there really no intellisense for vb.net ? In microsoft's own IDE ?

thanks

Comment: As you can see, just about everything in VS Code is achieved through extensions. Even C# Intellisense is done that way. Anyone who feels that it's worthwhile can provide an Intellisense extension for VB.NET.  The fact that there isn't one is an indication that there isn't that much demand for it.  Given the target audiences of VB.NET and VS Code, that's no surprise. The majority of people who would rather code in VB.NET than C# aren't going to be using VS Code.

Comment: Ok thank you for the confirmation that there isn't such a feature for vs code.  I thought vs code was basically a lightweight re-write of the big visual studio with an eye for portability. Only reason I don't see vb.net devs switching to is that it is missing essential features like debug and intellisense and the like. Is there another reason why vb.net dev would need the full visual studio ?

Comment: VS Code is NOT an IDE.  If you want an IDE then use Visual Studio.  VS Code is a code editor.  It is very much a code editor on steroids but it's still a code editor.  See [here](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-Visual-Studio-Code-vs-Visual-Studio-2015-RC): **Visual Studio Code isn't a "stripped down" version of Visual Studio as others have noted. It is, in fact, a Microsoft-built version of GitHub's Electron (formerly known as Atom Shell) – very much an entirely separate product.**

Comment: @jmcilhinney The quote you're citing is actually wrong as well. VSCode is not a "version" of Electron. Electron is a framework for building desktop apps, not an editor. Microsoft did not build an Electron version. It used Electron to implement Visual Studio Code. I also don't think calling VSCode an IDE is plain wrong. It has many IDE capabilities.

Answer (score 8):

As of 2018-08-28, there is no intellisense feature for vb.net in visual studio code nor is there an extension for it

Answer (score 5):

It's not much but there is a basic IntelliSense coverage of VB.NET syntax through this [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gordonwalkedby.vbnet).